# Set only the year in DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm new to C# and yes I found other answers but not quite what I want.

So I have a Car class which I assert now following values.

```
PKW Kaefer = new PKW("VW", "Käfer", "K-GS-01", DATETIMEVALUEHERE, 9999, 1000, 30, 1);
```

That datetime should be the year which the car was build.
That is my question, I only need the year and not anything else, and I also should be able to call it from

```
Console.WriteLine(Kaefer.Erstzulassung);
```

Here is my Car Class if anyone needs it

```
  public PKW(string hersteller,
        string modell,
        string kennzeichen,
        DateTime erstzulassung,
        double anschaffungspreis,
        double hubraum,
        int leistung,
        int schadstoffklasse
        )
        : base(hersteller, modell, kennzeichen, erstzulassung, anschaffungspreis)
    {
        this.Hubraum = hubraum;
        this.Leistung = leistung;
        this.Schadstoffklasse = schadstoffklasse;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you pass the datetime as a parameter then you can simply use it with `erstzulassung.Year`

Comment: The [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) structure returns details about the date if references: Year, Month, Day etc., conversion methods and provides means to alter the content: `AddYears`, `AddDays` etc.

Comment: A year is not a date. A date indicates a specific day (usually denoted as day+month+year). So, why would you want to use **Date**Time if you do not want to use it to represent a date? A year is simply a (integer) number, thus just store the number as such, as @einord suggested in their answer...

Comment: @Roobix13 if you want only the year (without day and month) then why don't you use the datatype of unsigned int instead of datetime. Alternatively the DateTime structure has a property of year which returns only the year part from a datetime value.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to only use an integer instead.

```
int erstzulassung
```

The `DateTime` struct is a struct that **has** to contain month, date & year.

Comment: yeah that was also one of my ideas, i tught there is a other way :/

Comment: The DateTime class always takes an entire date + time down to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no need to use DateTime class. Becouse, It is more complex, i mean you don't need other parameters that DateTime offer. for Example, Day or Month. So, it takes unnecessary storage. :) <3